# JQuery DataTabels - JQuery UI theme, arrows wrap on TH

Tags: jquery, css, datatables, nowrap

I am using datatables with a jquery ui theme, and for the columns that are sortable, some of the TH's wrap the little arrow icons used to sort that column.

I have about 7 columns being displayed. For the TDs that have small amount of text (that is no wider than the actual TH text) the arrow icon wraps on the TH. Any ideas on how to make it so that all the TH tags will not wrap the text? I tried adding 'sClass:nowrap' to every column and then creating a css nowrap class that uses white-space:nowrap, but that only works on the TD and not the TH.

Basically need a way to make sure the minimum width of every column is as wide as the TH contents (including the arrows)

Comment: That's strange, especially if it happens only with small amounts of text (although it shouldn't happen altogether). I guess you'd better post an example... (oh and use ` backticks if you add `<elements>` in your question, otherwise they won't show)

Answer (score 2):

Add this CSS to your page

```
<style type="text/css">
table.display thead th span.css_right {
  float: right;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have a tough time with this one, and I'd love to be proven wrong so that I can fix my own application. Here's why:

The default "Minimum Width" behaviour of any given column is the narrower of either the header text OR the widest word in any given column. An example to help clarify: Pretend there are no arrows for a moment-- you have a column with the header "Name", and the cells in that column are in the format "firstname [space] lastname". Somewhere in that column, one of the cells contains "Consuela Ruiz". The column can be as narrow as it takes to contain "Consuela" before it starts compensating according to its own algorithms.

So, for the arrows to be a part of that calculation, they have to be non-floated spans, making it trickier to position in the right side of each TH.

The compromise I ended up making was this:

1. Get the headers laid out the way you want. Figure out what widths you need to give them (in terms of % or px) so that the table is optimized according to the headers rather than the content.
2. Set the TD elements to have `overflow: hidden` and `text-overflow` ellipsis.
3. In the `fnDrawCallback` DataTables parameter (there might be a better place to do this, that's just what I happend to pick), set a function that takes every table cell and sets its contents to be its title (thereby allowing native tooltips to show truncated columns on hover).

Comment: It's also possible I'm not understanding the question. ;-) I don't know what "the arrow wraps the TH" means I don't think.

Comment: well I cant display it on here, as no line breaks are shown. Basicallly the arrows (^) should be displayed to the right of the text within the <th>. Instead, it places the arrows on a new line below the text. I discovered that using oTable.fnAdjustColumnSizing(); in the 'fInitComplete' option is what causes the problem. However, without the fnAdjustColumnSizing(), all columns are given equal widths which leaves a ton of space in columns with little text, and no space in columns with lots of text. stupid!

Comment: @JamesHickman I believe my answer stands, then-- it's going to be tricky. As an additional note, though, I do not use fnAdjustColumnSizing() on mine; instead, any columns that are clearly narrow, I give a px-based static width right in the markup (I believe there's a DT parameter you can use, instead). Then only the untouched columns get their widths equally distributed.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the thead th has no padding on the sides. Solved the issue for me!

Answer (score 1):

I too, am having this issue. After digging into the code, the base reason is when dataTables recalculates/repopulates the theads with jQuery UI, it inserts a floated span into the div, but doesn't wrap the original text with a floated span as well. So the code would look like this:

```
<th class="ui-state-default" style="width: 85px; ">
    <div class="DataTables_sort_wrapper">
        <!-- NEED FLOATED SPAN HERE-->Rate Package
        <span class="css_right ui-icon ui-icon-carat-2-n-s"></span>
    </div>
 </th>
```

Based on the float, it wraps it. There appears to be enough room in the th to accommodate both.  I'd suggest one of two things:

1. Specifiy th min-width/max-width through classes on the th tags.
2. Submit a fix ticket to datatables.net. I haven't had time to play around and dig in to the code too heavily.

Answer (score 1):

The wrapping problem is because of float right of th:after.
I found a solution playing with positions.
Just use this css:

```
table.dataTable thead th {
    position: relative;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
table.dataTable thead th:after {
    position: absolute !important;
    right: 0px;
}
```

With the padding-right I prevent overlapping and with position absolute the arrows can be positioned in the right side.